# CSS: Increase specificity of parent element

Tags: html, css

I have the following basic HTML structure:

```
<ul class = "foo">
   <li>
      <a href = "example.com">
       Click here
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
a:link {
   color: blue;
}

ul.foo li {
   padding: 2em;
   border: 1px solid black;
}

ul.foo li:hover {
   color: green;
}

ul.foo li:hover a {
   color: green;
}
```

So basically all links are blue, and `<LI>` elements inside `<UL>` elements of class `"foo"` have green text on hover.  The problem here, is that I want the `<A>` element that is a child of the `<LI>` element to have *green* text when the mouse hovers over the `<LI>` element.  But, because of the document-wide `a:link` selector, the link text in the `<a>` element remains blue *until* the mouse touches the link specifically.  But I want the link to turn green as soon as the mouse hovers over the enclosing `<LI>` element.

How can I accomplish this?  I know CSS uses "specificity" to decide which rules to apply, but I don't understand why the `ul.foo li:hover` selector is *less* specific than the document-wide `a` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have set the below:

```css
a:link {color: blue;}
```

All the `<a>` tags will be having blue colour, irrespective of the place. Moreover, `<a>` tag doesn't inherit the `color` property! So you would have to set it for all the `<a>`s.

So give this way:

```css
ul.foo li:hover a {color: green;} /* Or at least */
ul.foo li:hover a {color: inherit;}
```

Based on your comment:

> Sorry I wasn't clear: I actually do have `ul.foo li:hover a { color: green; }` - but that doesn't solve the problem I'm talking about - basically, I want the text in the `a` element to turn green when I hover over the parent `<LI>` element.

For this, you need to do like this:

```css
ul.foo li:hover a, ul.foo li:hover a:hover {color: green;}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: I actually do have `ul.foo li:hover a { color: green; }` - but that doesn't solve the problem I'm talking about - basically, I want the text in the `a` element to turn green when I hover over the *parent* `<LI>` element

Answer (score 0):

You are styling the `li` element on hover.  But if you want the text in the `<a>` tag to turn green , change your CSS to this to actually style the `<a>` tag:

```
ul.foo li:hover a {
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: Sorry - I edited my posted before you answered.  I actually already had that selector, (see above) but I left it out of my post.  Even with that selector, the `<a>` tag text only turns green when the mouse hovers over it - but my problem is I want it to turn green when the mouse hovers over the parent `<LI>` element